# Setting null password locks me out of updates

Tags: password

I changed the installation password to (none) after install which works great at boot. Now I cannot install updates because all administrative programs keep asking for a password and will not accept a NULL password nor the original password. Any way to fix this without a new install?

Comment: how about setting a new pass?

Comment: this post may help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Answer (score 0):

1. In `GRUB`, choose `recovery mode`.
2. Drop to `root` prompt. Use `passwd`:

`$ mount -o rw, remount /
 $ passwd <username>`

Use this to revert back to default password. You can also set any password you want, but that is not advisable as Ubuntu uses the same password for a lot of stuff (like encyption, keyrings...).

So it's better to update passwords via the settings menu, unless you know what you're upto.